# How to change direction of existing link in zoomcharts

Tags: hyperlink, zoomcharts

I'm trying to do it like this

```
function btnChangeDirClick(){
            var fromNode = document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkFrom").value;
            var toNode = document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkTo").value;
            chart.addData({
                        links:[{id:document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkid").value,
                             from:toNode,
                             to:fromNode
                             }]
                    });
        }
```

but my console returns

```
Changing link from,to not supported
```

Of course it's possible to delete and recreate, but are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I ended up implementing is as follows, which works fine:

```
        function btnChangeDirClick(){

            var fromNode = document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkFrom").value;
            var toNode = document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkTo").value;

            chart.removeData({links:[{id:document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkid").value}]});
            chart.addData({
                links:[{
                    "id":document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkid").value,
                     from:toNode,
                     to:fromNode,
                     "style":{label:document.getElementById("linkMenuLinklabel").value}
                     }]
                });
            nextId += 1;
            document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkFrom").value = toNode;
            document.getElementById("linkMenuLinkTo").value = fromNode;

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is to store a direction flag in data and assign from and to decorations depending on it.

I suggest using delete/recreate for now. Link reconnection support will come.

Comment: using decoration would work for me, because it complicates processing json having to check whether I can rely on the .from and .to or should switch them.

Comment: I implemented it using delete/recreate. solution included in original question